# Spark : add schema to dataset with missing columns

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a dataset `Dataset<Row> ds` like this:

```
col1 | col2 |
tom  | jerry|
```

I want to convert this dataset to this schema :

```
   StructType myModel = new StructType(new StructField[]{
    new StructField("col1", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("col2", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("col3", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty())
   });
```

What is the best way to do this ? I want to have a `Dataset<MyModel> ds` at the end, which has `col3` as null value (but this is a simplified example, there will be more columns with null values):

```
col1 | col2 | col3 |
tom  | jerry| null |
```